# OneSignal's Provisionator Tool doesn't authenticate: Incorrect 2 factor auth code

Tags: apple-push-notifications, onesignal

https://onesignal.com/provisionator always returns
"Incorrect 2 factor auth code! Please double check the code and try again." - when code is correct. Tried 3 times - always the same error.

Support suggests to manually generate certificates, though it's inconvenient. Did somebody was able to use provisionator recently?
If so - how do you login?

Please, vote for issue to bring support's attention, if you experience same problem with provisionator.

Answer (score 0):

> how do you login?

You log in in step 1 where it says enter your Apple credentials.

Perhaps double-check to ensure you're using the correct login.

Yes, alternatively you can always manually create the credentials.You can learn how to do that here: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/generate-an-ios-push-certificate#method-2-create-a-certificate-request-manually

Comment: at the moment 9 users voted for this issue - it's unlikely that they used wrong login. 
I assume you are member of OneSignal team (according to OneSignal logo on your avatar) please, ask your colleagues to fix the issue with 2-factor authentication - it's almost sure global issue for many or even all OneSignal's users.